# Move SharePoint list from one tenant to another tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-template, sharepoint-permissions

I am trying to move my SharePoint list from one tenant to another. In the SharePoint list settings, I couldn't find the option of "Save list as template".

Although I have full control of the SharePoint site. I have tried some settings from SharePoint admin center, but nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable Custom Script setting in SharePoint admin center?

Classic SharePoint admin center > settings > Custom Script

[image]

This change may take some time to reflect.

Comment: Yes, I enabled both of these settings from the SharePoint admin center.

Answer (score 0):

You can move SharePoint lists from one tenant to another using the Move-Lists tool: https://github.com/Zerg00s/Move-Lists Full disclosure - it's my pet project. It uses SharePoint PnP PowerShell under the hood.

- Open PowerShell and run `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope CurrentUser`
- [Download the latest release](https://github.com/Zerg00s/Move-Lists/releases)
- Unzip on disk.
- Run Move-Lists.bat file.

[image]

- Select source SharePoint Online site.
- Select destination SharePoint Online site.

[image]

- Select one or more Lists or Libraries to migrate.

[image]